# Get the min of two columns

Tags: r, dataframe, minimum

I want to get the minimum of two columns and create a column in the same *data.frame*. How can I do that?

For example:

```
ID    Parm1   Parm2
 1      1       2
 2      0       1
 3      2       1
 4      1       0
 5      2       0
```

Desired output :

```
ID    Parm1    Parm2     Min
 1      1        2        1
 2      0        1        0
 3      2        1        1
 4      1        0        0
 5      2        0        0
```

Comment: `data$Min <- with(data, pmin(Parm1, Parm2))`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You want the parallel minimum implemented in function `pmin()`. For example using your data:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "ID    Parm1   Parm2
 1      1       2
 2      0       1
 3      2       1
 4      1       0
 5      2       0", header = TRUE)
```

you can use `transform()` to add the `min` column as the output of `pmin(Parm1, Parm2)` and access the elements of `dat` without indexing:

```
dat <- transform(dat, min = pmin(Parm1, Parm2))
```

This gives:

```
> dat
  ID Parm1 Parm2 min
1  1     1     2   1
2  2     0     1   0
3  3     2     1   1
4  4     1     0   0
5  5     2     0   0
```

Comment: And `do.call(pmin, dat[-1])` if you have a host of variables and just want to exclude the first `ID` variable and save typing.

Comment: Thanks all for the answer ^_^

Comment: Today I learned this. I was using some very inefficient way to do this till now. thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Gavin, what if I require pmin but ignore 0?

Answer (score 16):

In tidyverse universe, using `dplyr` package:

```r
library(dplyr)

dat <- read.table(text = "ID    Parm1   Parm2
 1      1       2
 2      0       1
 3      2       1
 4      1       0
 5      2       0", header = TRUE)

dat %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(min = min(Parm1, Parm2))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#> # Rowwise: 
#>      ID Parm1 Parm2   min
#>   <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     1     1     2     1
#> 2     2     0     1     0
#> 3     3     2     1     1
#> 4     4     1     0     0
#> 5     5     2     0     0
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: If there are many columns and you just want to exclude column `ID` variable, similar to the proposal in comment by @thelatemail, use `dat %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(min = min(c_across(!ID)))` and save typing.

Answer (score 8):

In data.table way: `dat [, min := pmin(Parm1, Parm2)]`