# Get non-zero min of multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, minimum, sqldf

Similar to question here [Get the min of two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21977353/get-the-min-of-two-columns)

```
ID    Parm1   Parm2
 1      1       2
 2      0       1
 3      2       1
 4      1       0
 5      2       0
```

However, Desired output for Min is a non-zero minimum value

```
 ID    Parm1    Parm2     Min
 1      1        2        1
 2      0        1        1
 3      2        1        1
 4      1        0        1
 5      2        0        2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~na_if(.x,0)),
         Min = pmin(Parm1, Parm2, na.rm = TRUE))

  ID Parm1 Parm2 Min
1  1     1     2   1
2  2    NA     1   1
3  3     2     1   1
4  4     1    NA   1
5  5     2    NA   2
```

Comment: Can I get another column with the column name from which that min values is derived. e,g, 5th column would be ``` Param1 , Parm2, Parm2,Parm1,Parm1```